# Reverse Proxy - Select route depending on request path

Tags: c#, .net-core, reverse-proxy, appsettings

I have created a reverse proxy with .net Core 5.0 and it works so far. Now I want to change the destination depending on the requested URL. This is my appsettings.json:

```
 "ReverseProxy": {
"Routes": [
  {
    "RouteId": "route1",
    "ClusterId": "cluster1",
    "Match": {
      "Path": "{**catch-all}"
    }
  }
],
"Clusters": {
  "cluster1": {
    "Destinations": {
      "cluster1/destination1": {
        "Address": "http://192.168.178.36"
      }
    }
  },
  "cluster2": {
    "Destinations": {
      "cluster1/destination1": {
        "Address": "http://localhost:8080/signalr"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I know want that all requests are forwarded to my webserver. But if somebody starts a request with the path /signalr than it should be forwarded to my signalr server.
I tried also to use google, but as I see it the documentation related to the appsettings.json is so far really poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, my new apssettings.json:

```
"ReverseProxy": {
"Routes": [
  {
    "RouteId": "signalrServer",
    "ClusterId": "signalrServer",
    "Match": {
      "Path": "/signalr/{**catch-all}"
    }
  },
  {
    "RouteId": "mediaserver",
    "ClusterId": "mediaserver",
    "Match": {
      "Path": "/live/{**catch-all}"
    }
  },
  {
    "RouteId": "default",
    "ClusterId": "default",
    "Match": {
      "Path": "{**catch-all}"
    }
  }
],
"Clusters": {
  "default": {
    "Destinations": {
      "notfound": {
        "Address": "http://192.168.178.41/system/error/NotFound"            
      }
    }
  },
  "mediaserver": {
    "Destinations": {
      "mediaserver": {            
        "Address": "http://192.168.178.36"
      }
    }
  },
  "signalrServer": {
    "Destinations": {
      "signalrServer": {
        "Address": "http://localhost:8080"
      }
    }
  }
}
```